# How can i find wrong word in search box and replace with correct word

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, search, autocomplete

I have a search form and Many site users search for the wrong words, I want to replace these wrong words with the right ones so that users can get results faster.

I have been searching for this for several days but unfortunately I did not find any results.

I'm looking for a way if a user types wrong words like this

```
i love axqple
i love vaple
i love aple
i love applle
i love aplle
```

Replace the `wrong text` with `Apple`.

I have already checked things like the this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete) and this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426265/php-string-replace-match-whole-word) but have not reached a conclusion

I also looked at these cases:

[function str replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

[find word in variable and replace with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046835/php-find-word-in-variable-and-replace-with-another)

[search string for specific word and replace it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736165/search-string-for-specific-word-and-replace-it)

And many more...

Given this explanation, does anyone have a solution, educational content or any tips

Thanks for any help

Comment: See [Improving Native WordPress Search](https://torquemag.io/2018/04/improving-native-wordpress-search/)

Comment: Hi @MaxYudin, thank you for your time, but [this article](https://torquemag.io/2018/04/improving-native-wordpress-search/) was about the default WordPress search and the introduction of a few plugins, and can not help me,